# Windows XCOPY results from FIND command

Tags: windows-7, xcopy, findstr

Windows 7 CMD

I can retrieve a list of files by the following command `dir /b | find "TENDER_NUM 2"`. I'm trying to copy all the files that were returned by find into another folder.

I've tried:
`for /r %x in (dir /b | findstr "TENDER_NUM 2") do copy "%x" dir_to_copy\`

Which didn't work.

EDIT 1: Error message says `unexpected |`, which I assume is coming from the `dir/b | Findstr`

EDIT 2: Yes, dir_to_copy\ exists

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Does `dir_to_copy` exist?

Comment: @DavidPostill - updated question with both answers

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Error message says unexpected `|`

```
for /r %x in (dir /b | findstr "TENDER_NUM 2") do copy "%x" dir_to_copy\
```

There are multiple errors in the above command.

1. You need to escape the `|` special character using `^`:

   ```
   ^|
   ```
2. You need to enclose `dir /b | findstr "TENDER_NUM 2"` with single quotes `'`:

   ```
   'dir /b ^| findstr "TENDER_NUM 2"'
   ```
3. You need to use `for /f` instead of `for /r`:

   [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - **Loop command against the results of another command**.

   [for /r](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) - Loop through files (Recurse subfolders).

Use the following command from a `cmd` shell:

```
for /f %x in ('dir /b ^| findstr "TENDER_NUM 2"') do copy "%x" dir_to_copy\
```

In a batch file (replace `%` with `%%`):

```
for /f %%x in ('dir /b ^| findstr "TENDER_NUM 2"') do copy "%%x" dir_to_copy\
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [for /r](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) - Loop through files (Recurse subfolders).
- [syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) - Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes.

Comment: Thank you David, this is my initial foray into Windows CMD and the reading material is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're very welcome. Enjoy the reading! :)